# How to force Windows Server to accept only SSLv3 connections when using HTTPS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ssl, https, tls

I want to reproduce some production issue. For this purpose I need to configure my test Windows Server 2008 R2 to reject TLS connections and accept only SSLv3 connections when exposing IIS hosted web services over HTTPS. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This URL at the Microsoft support site will help you out:

[How to disable PCT 1.0, SSL 2.0, SSL 3.0, or TLS 1.0 in Internet Information Services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187498/en-us)